# Setting the icon color of a ListElement in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ListModal as follows:

```
ListModel {
                ListElement { icon: "qrc:/icons/gallery/20x20/profile.png"; icon.color: "transparent"; title: "Profile"; source: "qrc:/src/qml/pages/Profile.qml" }
                ListElement { icon: "qrc:/icons/gallery/20x20/lock.png"; icon.color: "transparent"; title: "Connect"; source: "qrc:/src/qml/pages/Connect.qml" }
            }
```

When my application uses the dark theme of a style (i.e Universal), my icons are hard to see. I would like them to have a transparent color so the color is inverted upon theme change, similar to this code:

```
ListView {
    id: listView

    focus: true
    currentIndex: -1
    anchors.fill: parent

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        width: parent.width
        text: model.title
        icon.source: model.icon
        icon.height: 20
        icon.width: 20
        icon.color: "transparent"
        highlighted: ListView.isCurrentItem
        onClicked: {
            listView.currentIndex = index
            stackView.push(model.source)
            drawer.close()
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can do this easily?

Comment: What do you mean saying `do this easily`? That doesn't look too complicated. Or replace `ItemDelegate` with `Image` ... what could be easily.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used themes or styles much, but I believe you can specify the icon's color depending on what theme is currently in use with a ternary operator:

```
icon.color: (Material.theme === Material.Dark) ? "white" : "black"
```